# Writing a function that converts "12#abcd#09bla" into "abcd"

Tags: c, string, function

So with a lot of trial and error I did it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


/*Prototype of a hashtag function*/
void hashtag(char *,char *);

int main()
{
    /* Declaration of strings S and P*/
    char S[100], P[100]="";

    /*Getting the string S from a keyboard*/
    printf("Unesi string S: ");
    gets(S);

    /*Calling "hashtag"*/
    hashtag(S,P);
}
/*Hashtag function*/
void hashtag(char *S,char *P)
{
    /*Finding the position of 2 #'s in string S*/
    int i, t1, t2;
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        if(S[i]=='#')
        {
            t1=i;
            break;
        }
    }
    for(i=100;i>0;i--)
    {
        if(S[i]=='#')
        {
            t2=i;
            break;
        }
    }
    /*"Filling" the empty string P with the text in between #'s*/
    int k;
    for(i=t1+1,k=0;i<t2,k<(t2-t1-1);i++,k++)
    {
        P[k]=S[i];
    }
    puts(P);
}
```

Why do I have this awful feeling that this is ridiculously overcomplicated? I have a feeling that finding the exact positions wasn't necessary and that it could've been done much simpler than this.

Comment: better fit for codereview?

Comment: I would think of it more as `12(abcd)09bla` or `12"abcd"09bla` to get your head around in.

Comment: `for(i=100;i>0;i--)`????? You've got to go `for(i=99;i>=0;i--)`!!!!!

Comment: @IdeaHat rather `12(abcd(09bla`?

Comment: @NickT yeah the unbalanced parens is why I decided to put the quotes in. Read up to delim, copy to delim, print 0, done.

Comment: @user2366842 Could be, honestly, I still have a hard time understanding exactly how this site works, I'm that new. The layout confuses me a bit.

Comment: -barakmanos Actually you're right, I fixed that.
-IdeaHat Not sure what you're suggesting. What's the difference between finding the exact spot of "'s instead of #'s? 
I was wondering maybe there was an entire different way of doing this, which might be better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void hashtag(char *S, char *P){
    sscanf(S, "%*[^#]#%[^#]", P);
    puts(P);
}
```

Comment: Well that's... Easier. Didn't ever hear of sscanf. Now that I think about it, it could've been done with strchr and strrchr also, right?

Comment: @slamdunker you can rewrite your code using `strchr` and `strrchr`. My code different from that exactly.

Comment: Better of `strrchr` than `for(i=99;i>=0;i--)`.

Comment: Could I have a link to how sscanf works in these types of problems? I can find million others, and I think I understand the %[^#] part of it, but not exactly the rest.

Comment: part of `%*[^#]` to skip the characters up to `#`.  `%[^#]` to read  the characters up to `#`.

Comment: What about the # in the middle? 
The * in %*[^#] is to skip characters up to #? Or is it the # after the [^#] part?

Comment: Suggest checking the `sscanf()` return value.

Comment: @slamdunker Since `%*[^#]` does not read the `#`. middle's `#` discard reading `#`(skip first #).

Comment: Okay, I think I got it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to do it with `strchr` only. This function does not output `p`, but it returns `-1` on failure, i.e. when the function wasn't able to find two `#` signs.

```
int hashtag(const char *s, char *p)
{
    const char *end;

    /*
     * We want to have s point right after the first #. strchr() makes
     * s point to the first # or NULL if no # is found. In the if, we
     * check for that and sneakingly increment s so it points right
     * after the first #.
     */
    s = strchr(s, '#'); 
    if (s++ == NULL)
        return (-1);

    /* this makes end point to the second #, like before */
    end = strchr(s, '#');
    if (end == NULL)
        return (-1);

    /* copy the text between the two # signs into p */
    memcpy(p, s, end - s - 1);
    p[end - s] = '\0'; /* terminate p with a '\0' as it is a string */

    return (0); /* success */
}
```

Comment: This one works good too, thank you! The problem with it is that it has a lot of elements that I don't know yet, and I'm trying to study for the exam tomorrow, so - no time to google every other line of it. :D

Comment: If you have questions about the code, feel free to ask. In the meanwhile, I will add some comments.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have tons of questions but no time, I have to do bunch of functions and then move on to sorting algorithms and working with files. And I have about 20 hours to do it all, so yeah. I'll bookmark this page tho, thank you for the effort! I wish I could vote up but it says I don't have enough reputation for it.

Comment: @slamdunker You should now be able to upvote things.